# How to use shepherd with jquery in ionic 3?

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework, plugins

I'm trying to build a touring in my ionic 3 app, so I choose [Shepherd](https://shipshapecode.github.io/shepherd/) to implement it.

But in ionic 3, it's a typescript framework, so we cannot directly call jQuery in html file but in .ts file. And shepherd has a function call 'addStep' like

```
tour.addStep('example-step', {
    text: 'Testing',
    attachTo: '.example-css-selector bottom',
    classes: 'example-step-extra-class',
    buttons: [
       {
          text: 'Next',
          action: tour.next
       }
    ]
});
```

So, I've already installed jQuery and shepherd plugin. But when trying the code below, it won't work.

in home.html

```
<p>Title</p>
<button id="shepherdElement">Click Me</button>
```

in home.ts

```
const tour = new Shepherd.Tour();

tour.addStep('example-step', {
      text: 'Testing',
      attachTo: $('#shepherdElement')
  });

tour.start();
```

I expect the tour would attach to #shepherdElement but it's not.

actual image [image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about accessing through Jquery but if id selector is only your problem then you can access that in following way.

```
const tour = new Shepherd.Tour();
tour.addStep('example-step', {
  text: 'Testing',
  attachTo: '#shepherdElement'
  });
tour.start();
```